# Disconnecting Many-to-Many Relationships in Prisma + MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, prisma

I am so completely lost. I have an explicit many to many relation: Users can have multiple Lists, but lists can be owned by multiple users:

```
model List {
    id        String                @id @default(cuid())
    title     String
    users     UsersOnLists[]
}

model User {
    id        String                @id @default(cuid())
    name      String
    lists     UsersOnLists[]
}

model UsersOnLists {
    id    String @id @default(cuid())
    order Int

    user   DictItem? @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId String?
    list   List? @relation(fields: [ListId], references: [id])
    listId String?
}
```

Now I'd like to connect a list to a user:

```
prisma.list.update({
        where: {
          id: input.id
        },
        data: {
          users: {
            create: [{
              order: 123,
              user: {
                connect: {
                  id: "abcd-123",
                }
              }
            }],
          }
        }
      });
```

This works.

However, I don't know how to go about disconnecting many-to-many relations in prisma? Say I want to disconnect the user again from the list? How would I do this?

```
prisma.list.update({
        where: {
          id: input.id
        },
        data: {
          users: {
            disconnect: [{
              user: {
                disconnect: {
                  id: "abcd-123",
                }
              }
            }],
          }
        }
      });
```

This doesn't work.

I also can't find much in the prisma docs about disconnecting. Any ideas?

I guess I could jus delete the row from the Relations-Table, but this doesn't feel as clean and I guess I would still have the old ids in the user & list tables? I would prefer using `disconnect`, if this is the recommended method for that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a specific error? If you are using a code editor/IDE with TypeScript hinting, it should be giving you a specific error(s) about what's going on. If not that, then the command line should be giving you errors when you attempt to run an operation.

Docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#disconnect-a-related-record

The "disconnect" operation cannot disconnect deeply-nested relations. It only disconnects documents directly connected to the model in question. In your situation, you can only disconnect a `UserOnList` from a `List`, but you cannot also disconnect `User` from `UserOnList` in the same operation.

```js
prisma.list.update({
    where: {
        id: input.id
    },
    data: {
        users: {
            disconnect: [{
                id: "ID_OF_UsersInList_MODEL_HERE"
            }],
        }
    }
});
```

Also - you don't **need** the `UsersInList` table. Prisma can manage the "join" table under the hood for you if you don't need any extra information or data on that model. Check out the docs here if you want Prisma to manage this table on its own: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations

Comment: I would love to use an implicit relationship here, but I need users to order what's shown in the lists, which is why i have the `order` field on my relations table. Do you know if there is a way I can have users order their lists, whilst using *implicit* many to many relations (i.e. without the `UsersOnList` table)?

Comment: I just tried out the `disconnect` solution you provided & it works. However, as you say, it will only disconnect one connection. Would it make more sense to just delete that row from the relations table then? Or is this a bad way to do it, because there will be uncleaned ghost-data left over in other tables?

Comment: 1. Do you mean sort order when you talk about `order`? If the sort order is the detail of a user, maybe store that on the `User` so it applies to every list, then you can use the implicit relation. 2. Using `disconnect` on one side of the relation will automatically disconnect it from the other side. So if you disconnect `User` from `List` (or `List` from `UserInList`), it will automatically disconnect it on the other side of the relationship

Comment: 1. Users can order the items on their lists. So one item might appear in position 1 for user A, but in position 4 for user B etc. 2. Since I am using a many-to-many relationship, I need to disconnect `User` from `UsersOnLists` and `List` from `UsersOnList` -that's what I am talking about. So it seems like I need to make 2 calls to get rid of both relations, plus a third call to delete the row in the `UsersOnLists` table - is this correct?

Comment: 1. got it, you might want the join table. 2. If you just delete the row in `UsersOnLists` that should automatically disconnect the relationship from `User` and `List` - have you tried _just_ deleting the `UsersOnLists` entry?